# API POST Response only reading last record of dataframe converted to list, how to change?

Tags: python, pandas, python-requests, api-design

I am trying to pass data through a POST command into a API. The API only takes data formatted in the C`ontent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`format. I am not familiar with this format yet. Information about the particular API call I am trying to make can be found here. `https://www.activecampaign.com/api/example.php?call=contact_add`

The data sits in a dataframe with the following fields.

```
     email                 p[1]*
0     belle@yandex.com      1
1  apple765@yandex.com      1
2   pear432@yandex.com      1
```

According to the documentation `p[1]` is the field to specify what list I want the data to go into.

The code I am running is as follows:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'email':['belle@yandex.com','apple765@yandex.com','pear432@yandex.com'], 'p[1]*':1})

#I think Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded formated data takes list format#

df1 = df1.to_dict(orient = 'list')

url = 'https://URL/admin/api.php?api_action=contact_add&api_output=json&api_key=123ABC' 

resp = requests.post(url, data=df1, headers=headers)

print(resp.text)
```

The response object `resp` returns 200, but in the email campaign list I only see the last email address in row 2 appear only. Why is this ? what am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well basically servers confirms creation of objects by sending 201 status code, but some servers return 200 instead. I wonder if you already created these objects...
I'm also not sure that you need the asterisk after p[1] (after quick look at the documentation I think that p should only points to the list ID), but that's for you to check.

Comment: you are right asterick is not needed. Now I can not figure out how to iterrate the dataframe per email address into the api. Any thoughts how to do this?

Comment: So it looks like you can add a single record in each request, so if you want to iterate over the emails within the Dataframe you should do something like that:

for email in df1['email']:
    # send request
    resp = requests.post(url, data={'email': email, 'p[1]':1})

Comment: Great! Glad to help mate!